# Proof that a sequence is bounded by inspection of series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum\limits c_n$  converges absolutely and $\sum\limits c_nk_n $ also converges absolutely, then $k_n$ must be bounded. How do I prove this? I think this can be proven by contradiction. Anyone?

Comment: $c_n = \dfrac{1}{n^3}$, $k_n = n$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that if $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely and $k_n$ is bounded, then $\sum c_nk_n$ coverges absolutely?

Comment: thomas andrews. no it is right the way i wrote.

Comment: @njguliev Even worse: $c_n=0$ and $k_n=$ what you want...

Comment: Danny, you've defaced a couple of your questions recently. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement might be:

> A sequence $(k_n)$ is bounded if and only if, for every absolutely convergent series $\sum\limits c_n$, the series $\sum\limits c_nk_n $ converges absolutely.

If $(k_n)$ is bounded, the conclusion holds. If $(k_n)$ is unbounded, for every integer $i\geqslant1$, choose $n(i)$ such that $|k_{n(i)}|\geqslant i$ and assume the integers $n(i)$ are all different (can you see why such a sequence $(n(i))$ always exists?). Define $(c_n)$ by $c_{n(i)}=1/i^2$ and $c_n=0$ if $n$ is not one of the $n(i)$s. Then the series $\sum\limits c_n$ is absolutely convergent because $\sum1/i^2$ is, while the series $\sum\limits c_nk_n $ is not because $\sum1/i$ is not.